# Superposition principle in sinusoidal waves

Tags: waves, superposition, linear-systems

In sinusoidal wave equations that produce interference  we simply add their displacements by superposition principle, however superposition position principle can be applied to only linear equations.
So what's the deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What allows superposition is that the wave equation

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$

is linear in the “waving” variable $u$... for example, the string displacement for a string stretched along $x$. This linearity means that if $u_1(x,t)$ and $u_2(x,t)$ are solutions, then so is their sum. The fact that this linear differential equation has sinusoidal (and many other) solutions $u(x, t)$ that, for fixed $t$, are not linear functions of the coordinate $x$ is irrelevant.

Comment: By u do you mean y displacement?? If yes then let me just ask this for confirmation linearity should be in the main variable whose change I am considering??

Comment: If the string is vibrating in the $xy$ plane, then the displacement $u$ is $y$. Yes, linearity of the dynamical equation in the variable that is changing is what matters.

Answer (score 1):

The wave equation is a linear operator, ie: $L(x+y)=L(x)+L(y)$.
Define the wave equation operator $$L(u)=u_{xx}-\frac{1}{c^2}u_{tt}$$
where u is the solution and c is the speed of propagation.
Then the wave equation is $$L(u)=0$$
and since its linear$$L(u_1+u_2)=0$$ where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are any functions that have first and second derivatives.

So to answer your question you can add the sinusoids because the wave equation is a linear *operator*--re. G Smiths answer.

Comment: What is a linear operator? I forgot to mention that I am in high school and this seems like something from higher calculus or something. Can you provide something that i can refer to?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Google 'linear operator'.  'operator' is a function that operates on functions instead of numbers--like a normal function does.  Linearity is one of the most important concepts you will run into. It applies to both functions and operators--and is basically defined by my equation for $L(x+y)=L(x)+L(y)$.

Comment: A simple linear example would be: apples= 1 dollar ea and pears=2 dollars ea so one apple plus one pear=3.dollars  This could be made non linear by adding that you get the second fruit for half price, then one apple plus one pear=2 dollars.